Inconsistency between Horizons data retrieved via Astroquery and Horizons web interface
I am attempting to obtain the x, y, z coordinates of the Sun-asteroid vector using Horizons.
The code I wrote is:
jd_tdb = Time(2457171.6650230, format='jd', scale='utc').tdb.value
obj_sun = Horizons(id=21, location='500@10',
        epochs=jd_tdb, id_type='smallbody')
vec_sun = obj_sun.vectors()

The obtained values are:

However, the Horizons website and/or the 'raw_response' in Astroquery provide:

So, there is a small difference (but important for astrometric purposes) between the outputs.

Does anyone have insight into the issue?
Thank you.

I dont know Astroquery (but I do know Horizons, and Python). I think the difference is due to a time scale issue. The Horizons query is using TDB, but your original Astroquery call looks like it's using UTC.

I think that I am converting to tdb here: Time(2457171.6650230, format='jd', scale='utc').tdb.value. So, the inputs should be the same as far as I understand.

Yes, but your original call uses JD 2457171.6650230 UTC, but the Horizons output is for JD 2457171.6650230 TDB.

This does the resolution of this astroquery issue help at all?

@Roy Interesting. The Horizons record for 21 Lutetia has the Solution date: 2024-Feb-23_20:13:24 https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=21%3B

As @PM 2Ring pointed out in the comments, there was a problem between TDB and UTC times (the difference between them is small but impacts the x,y, and z results).
Now, comparing the solution and the raw response, we get the same:

Thank you so much for your useful comments!

Happy ending, yay! You can also check the "accept" button so future readers know the problem was solved.
